# not work mouseenter event when load panel with ajax

Tags: jquery

i append a button to div when mouseenter event fire, but when refresh panel with load function by using $.ajax() to add create item, mouseenter event not work

```
<script>
 $(function Bindmouseenter() {
    $('.divitemList').mouseenter(function () { $(this).append('<input onclick="DeletePriority($(this).parent())" value="حذف" type="button" class="btn-danger btnDeletePriority" />') })
    $('.divitemList').mouseleave(function () { $('.btnDeletePriority').remove() });
});
```

and call bellow script when item added to panel for refresh panel items

```
<script>
    function GoToPriorityPnl() {
        $('#PriorityPnl').load('GoToPriority')
        $('ul').empty();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) `.on(event, selector, handler)`